# Overt Subjects of Non-Finite Clauses and Accusative Case

Tags: cases, clauses, infinitive

How do overt subjects of non-finite clauses such as the gerund clause below obtain accusative case despite there being no accusative case or ECM assigner?

```
Me arriving late is a sure thing
```

I think I can figure out how they get case if the verb of the matrix clause is a regular non-copular verb as in the sentence below with a perception verb, but the sentence above having a copula as the matrix verb makes it very difficult to analyse because I don't think the subject is able to obtain ECM from the copula.

```
I saw him eating the cake.
```

Comment: The subject smuggles in ECM from a private supplier.

Comment: @jlawler And who would that private supplier be?

Comment: I don't follow you. The matrix clause "Me arriving late to work" is a gerund-participial clause. The embedded clause "to work" is subjectless infinitive clause; the understood subject "me" is determined syntactically from the matrix. Subjects of gerund-participial clauses can also be in the genitive case, cf. "**My** arriving late to work ...". Btw, your example is not natural. Are you sure you meant "late to work"?

Comment: @BillJ I got the terms 'infinitive' and 'non-finite' mixed up. The subject of the non-finite gerund clause is the one in question. The clause "to work" has nothing to do with this and could be omitted as in "me arriving late is a sure thing". How is the accusative subject "determined syntactically"? The question asks how it gets accusative case.

Comment: Non-finite gerund-participial clauses can generally take accusative or genitive subjects, so both _Me arriving late ..._ and _My arriving late_ are possible. When I said "determined syntactically", I was referring to the subject of the embedded infinitival clause _to work_, where the subject "me" is obtained from the matrix clause, i.e. syntactically. As to why: I don't know; perhaps it has something to do with Latin.

Comment: My guess is that the reason is diachronic rather than synchronic. We know that we have sentences like 'For you to depart would be sad' came about because sentences like 'It would be [sad [for you] [to depart]]' were reanalysed as 'It would be [sad [for [you to depart]]]'. Probably the same happened here: 'I saw [him] [eating the cake]' became 'I saw [him eating the cake]' and hence '[Him eating the cake] is something I saw' became an acceptable sentence.

Comment: @WavesWashSands I see your point. Your derivation of the sentence with "saw" as the main verb sounds okay since you have "saw" to assign accusative case, but it doesn't seem to be applicable to the sentence "me arriving late is a sure thing" because if you reverse the derivation, you'd get a sentence like " it is a sure thing me arriving late", which doesn't seem to be the same as a tough-movement sentence due to the comma-intonation (signalling it's an appositive): "it is a sure thing--me arriving late". Even if we use this derivation, we still don't know where the accusative case comes from.

Comment: @Morphosyntax I think you misunderstood my point slightly... As I said, my proposal was diachronic, not synchronic; I don't mean to imply any synchronic transformational rules. What I meant was that after patterns like 'him eating the cake' appeared in postverbal position, English speakers reanalysed the whole 'accusative noun + participle phrase' pattern as a possible way to nominalise clauses, and thus the pattern can now be used in other contexts requiring nominals as well.